# Create a hyperlink from part of a text submitted in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to create a form that allows text to be transformed into hyperlink.

For example, StackOverflow allows us to create a link by following the syntax:

```markdown
To create fancier links, use Markdown:
Here's [a link](http://www.example.com/)!
```

So when the form is submitted, `[a link]` actually becomes a link that takes you to www.example.com.

Any ideas?

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Please edit your question to include what you'e tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

create an

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

element and then change the `href` attribute and text to be

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"> your link </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a form with 2 inputs(first for href and second for display name) and on submit you create a function that append or create a new "a" element with submitted href and display text.

Answer (score 1):

Create a for with input field and a button and an a tag where the entered text value will be shown on button click, add jquery .attr() method to set the href value of a tag.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();      $('a').html(inputvalue).attr("href",inputvalue);
    });
});
```